# How create a Typescrip type guard for a ReactElement type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-types, typeguards

I have three Typescript type guards:

```
  const isTeaserOne = (teaser: Teaser): teaser is TeaserOneType =>
    typeof teaser === 'object' && teaser.type.includes('One');
  const isTeaserTwo = (teaser: Teaser): teaser is TeaserTwoType =>
    typeof teaser === 'object' && teaser.type.includes('Two');
  const isSpecialTeaser = (teaser: Teaser): teaser is SpecialTeaserType =>
    typeof teaser === 'function';
```

The `SpecialTeaserType` type:

```
export type SpecialTeaser = ReactElement;
```

This type is returning a jsx component:

```
copyArray[5] = <MyComponent />;
```

How do I create a type guard for this `ReactElement`?

Comment: This question is unclear: we don’t know the type of `Teaser`, and if `type Teaser = TeaserOneType | TeaserTwoType | SpecialTeaserType`, the implementation you have should be fine, so it’s not clear what the problem is. You also have `SpecialTeaserType` and `SpecialTeaser`: are these the same thing? You seem to say they are, but it is unclear. If they are different, is the problem that you want to tell them apart? We would need the definition of `SpecialTeaserType` then.

Answer (score -1):

Try this pattern:

```
interface Props {
  variant: “TypeOne” | “TypeTwo”
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props): JSX.Element => { 
<>
  props.variant === “TypeOne” && return (/*JSX*/)
  props.variant === “TypeTwo” && return (/*JSX*/)
</>
}
```